# display flex blocks in 3 columns with correct order

Tags: css, sass, flexbox, compass

is something like this achievable with flexbox or any other css technique not involving putting each column inside wrapper?

[image]

best result aligns them in correct order, but 4th element is under longest container not under element above it.

I'm using compass, and at the moment my scss is:

```
  ul.level0 {
    @include display-flex;
    @include flex-flow(row wrap);
    @include justify-content(flex-end);
    @include align-items(flex-start);
    @include align-content(flex-start);

    .menu-group {
      @include display-flex(inline-flex);
      vertical-align: top;
      width: 33.33%;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
      padding: 0 5px;

      li {
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
        margin-bottom: 3px;
      }

      .group-title {
        margin-bottom: 12px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: nop, it breaks into lines and all elements gets the same height(tallest on line sets the height)

Comment: in fact elemnt heights are correct, they are not stretched to match line height (not adapting to largest element)

Comment: actually it does with flex-wrap and order , http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxjQLe my mistake :)

Answer (score 3):

You may use flex-wrap , flex-direction and order:

```css
ul {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  height:300px;
  margin:1em;
  padding:0;
  list-style-type:none;
}
li {height:80px;
border:solid;
width:30%;
margin:1em;
order:5}
li:nth-child(odd) {
  height:40px;
}
li:first-child {
  height:100%;
}
li:nth-child(1) {
  order:1
}
li:nth-child(2) {
  order:2
}
li:nth-child(3) {
  order:4
}
li:nth-child(4) {
  order:3
}
li:nth-child(5) {
  order:5
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: interesting, it works in codepen, but not inside my page, flex-direction:column; just puts all li elements 1 under other in 1 column.

Comment: @pankijs That's because column orientation requires an explicit height in order to force wrapping.

Comment: It is kind of sad that such nice answers often earn so little recognition

Comment: @NicoO answer kinda works, but it is not correct in my case, there is fixed height involved, but I need universal solution since column heights varies depending of content, so no fixed height. I upvoted this answer, but it is not suitable for me. ended up using jquery and absolute positions. :(

Comment: @pankijs can you give an example of html with content (fake or real) close to what you have to deal with?

Comment: @pankijs you can use/play with this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBXzzZ i'll be offline a few days

Comment: @GCyrillus http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dPKpvm, im trying to position "Highlights" http://i.imgur.com/YLuzAfa.png , 1st, 2nd and 3rd group will be changing couple of times in a month.

Comment: @GCyrillus real problem is that elements have to be in order 1234 and aligned in right side, so if I have 4, 4th will be on right side, if I have 2 1st will be in middle and 2nd will be on right side and so on.